# git ls-remote succeeds while go get fails

Tags: go, go-modules

git ls-remote command succeeds for a repo as shown below.

```
git ls-remote https://internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo
warning: redirecting to https://internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git/
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    HEAD
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    refs/heads/master
```

However, when go get is used the cmd fails with repository not found. The error output tries to find .git at 1 directory above the repository structure.

```
go get internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo@master
go: internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo@master: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/{{UserId}}/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/xyz...: exit status 128:
    remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
    fatal: repository 'https://internal.net/dir1/dir2.git/' not found
```

My goprivate is
`GOPRIVATE=internal.net`

What am I missing here for the go get to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a VCS suffix to the private module path to mark the repository root prefix:

```
go get internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git@master
```

See [Direct access to private modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-proxy-direct):

> An internal HTTP server may still be needed to [resolve module paths to repository URLs](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-find). For example, when the go command downloads the module `corp.example.com/mod`, it will send a GET request to `https://corp.example.com/mod?go-get=1`, and it will look for the repository URL in the response. To avoid this requirement, ensure that each private module path has a VCS suffix (like `.git`) marking the repository root prefix. For example, when the go command downloads the module `corp.example.com/repo.git/mod`, it will clone the Git repository at `https://corp.example.com/repo.git` or `ssh://corp.example.com/repo.git` without needing to make additional requests.

Please note that the VCS suffix is a part of the module path, so it should be included in all the places where a module path is used. Including:

1. the `module` directive

   ```
   module internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git
   ```
2. the `require` directive

   ```
   require internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git v0.0.1
   ```
3. the import declaration

   ```
   import "internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git/pkg/util"
   ```
4. and more.

Comment: thanks. can confirm adding .git can get the package but now i'm pondering how would the go.mod file look like? will it include the .git or not?
it should include .git since the go get would have pulled the version under a directory which has .git.



Lets say there is a pkg/util provided by the repo.git

if it includes .git, then how would the package import look like?
import "internal.net/dir1/dir2/dir3/repo.git/pkg/util" ?? This syntax doesn't look right to me

Comment: @GanapathyRamachandran I just had a try myself and updated the answer to clarify that VCS suffix is a part of the module path. It does not look right to me too. Will you consider creating an internal HTTP serve to resolve module paths to repository URLs?